# When does Adam choose and install Directives?

Tags: android-netrunner

Adam's ID ability is, "You start the game with 3 different directive cards installed (these cards are not considered part of your deck)." Now (since Escalation) that there are more than 3 options for Directives to install, when does the Runner choose which ones to use, especially in a tournament situation? Must it be consistent between games? Can it be done after seeing the Corp ID?

Comment: I would also like an official ruling on this, but my interpretation is that you can choose directives any time up until you "start the game," which would likely mean after you've seen the corp ID, although I'm not familiar with this aspect of tournament etiquette. There's nothing in the card that says to me that the directives must be consistent between games, in fact the "not part of your deck" clause suggests that these cards are not subject to normal deck construction rules.

Comment: That interpretation would seem consistent with the way a rebirth works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android: Netrunner lead designer Damon Stone has [confirmed](http://twitter.com/iLogos/status/785613284405673984) on Twitter that Adam's directives are chosen and revealed after players' IDs are revealed.